# Does '!contains' can "compare" String with String in Karate?

Tags: karate

We read very carefully the github repo, but we can't find if we can do:
'foo' !contains 'bar'. Exemples show only: 
* match foo !contains { huh: '#notnull' } > json
* match foo !contains 4 > int
* match foo !contains [5, 6] > array

Can we do it with String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, this is indeed not possible today, but we opened a ticket for this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/201

Meanwhile you can do this via an `assert` and JavaScript:

```
* def foo = 'Hello World'
* assert foo.indexOf('blah') == -1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Peter Thomas, for your quick reply. We really enjoy karate. In fact we needed to find `String != String` , the opposite of `And match String == String`. As we didn't find, we used `!contains`, but contains is not equal. Is there an opposite of `==`? Thanks.

Comment: @nirind not equals `!=` will be possible for all data types in the next version of karate 0.6.1 - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/201

Comment: thanks for notification. I'll subscribe to karate repo on github