# match - Combining values from API

Tags: karate

```
* def a2Company = get a2Names $..companyName //["TEST ABC"]
* def a1Company1 = get a1Names $..companyName1 //["TEST"]
* def a1Company2 = get a1Names $..companyName2 //["ABC"]
* def a1Company = a1Company1 + a1Company2 // ["TEST"]["ABC"]
* match a2Company contains a1Company1 // this fails
```

I am comparing two APIs and for one of the value in api 2 is a combination of 2 values from api1

The above doesnt seem to work
I tried with javascript with concat but same issue

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would be great if you could provide a running example that represents your use case and demonstrate your problem.

I guess that you interpret `match .. contains ...` as `string contains`, but it doesn't. 

It looks like you try to apply `contains` on a string `TEST ABC` and an array `['TEST']['ABC']`. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you are right.. I tried defining company1 and company 2 as strings but still the comparison fails

Comment: If you are looking for a string contains, maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491555/does-contains-can-compare-string-with-string-in-karate helps you.

Comment: I looked it up and it seems it should work for 0.9.2 version of Karate... and I am using 0.9.2...

Comment: What should work? String contains? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: How do i match array values?

Comment: I'm hoping that ['Test abc'] contains ['Test'] would work? Sorry if I was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match x contains y` works on the types of `x` and `y`. If these two are of type `array` than contains means that the array `x` contains all values of the array `y`.

Example:

```
    Scenario: Contains with arrays
    * def x = ["test", "abc"]
    * def y = ["test"]
    * def z = ["abc"]
    * match x contains y
    * match x contains z
```

If `x` and `y` are strings, then contains means that the string `y` can be found in `x`, `x` contains `y`. Does this make sense?

Example:

```
  Scenario: Contains with string
    * def x = "test abc"
    * def y = "test"
    * def z = "abc"
    * match x contains y
    * match x contains z
```

You try to mix these things. You have arrays, but you want to apply string contains on array values. That doesn't work, because karate doesn't know, that you want to apply the contains an the values of a single valued array.

A workaround could be:

```
  Scenario: Test array value contains string
    * def x = ["test abc"]
    * def y = ["test"]
    * match x[0] contains y[0]
```

Does this help you?